# Passing quoted arguments to a REBOL 3 script

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I've found it almost impossible to pass quoted arguments (containing spaces) to REBOL 3 scripts. For example:

```
rebol -q script.r "foo bar" 40
```

If you examine `system/script/args`, it contains the string `"foo bar 40"`. This is useless! Information was lost. I need to know that `"foo bar"` was the first argument and `40` was the second. If I examine `system/options/args`, I get the following block: `["foo" "bar" "40"]`. Again, useless! Information was lost.

I suspect that the solution to this is to use argument delimiters of some kind, e.g.,

```
rebol -q script.r 'foo bar' -n 40
```

This could easily be handled by `PARSE`, but I still don't like it. It shouldn't be terribly difficult for `system/options/args` to contain one string per passed argument.

REBOL's a pleasure to use, and this is the first thing I've found with which I was really disappointed. :(

Comment: Am I right to suspect that you are talking about REBOL 3 here? (The above (mis-)behaviour seems to be not present in REBOL 2.)

Comment: I observed the same behaviour on 2.7.7 OS X.

Comment: @earl Yeah, REBOL 3. Haven't tried it in REBOL 2, which I never use anymore. (I can get away with that because REBOL is chiefly a hobby language for me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In REBOL 3, the behaviour you observe [is a known bug](http://issue.cc/r3/1890).

(At the moment, R3 internally passes args from the OS to scripts as a single string, concatenating all original arguments in the process. Currently this process is not fully reversible, which is the cause of this bug. R3 probably should_ pass arguments as a list of strings instead, effectively preserving the original `argv` but stripped of arguments used by the interpreter itself.)

---

In REBOL 2, `system/options/args` is safer to use for command-line arguments, whereas `system/script/args` can be used to pass values between REBOL scripts more directly. I assume that similar behaviour will be kept for R3.

Here's a quick script to inspect argument parsing behaviour:

```
REBOL []
print system/version
print "options args:"
probe system/options/args
print "script args:"
probe system/script/args
```

REBOL 2, on OSX:

```
2.7.7.2.5
options args:
["foo bar" "40"]
script args:
"foo bar 40"
```

REBOL 3, on OSX:

```
2.100.111.2.5
options args:
["foo" "bar" "40"]
script args:
"foo bar 40"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the quotes:

```
rebol -q script.r \"foo bar\" 40
```

Don't know if this is a shortcoming of shell or REBOL?

Comment: It looks like it is shortcoming of REBOL, because all other programs (batch scripts, C programs etc.) accept a double quoted string as one argument.

Comment: Under the hood the shell is throwing away the quotes, but still is passing Rebol `argv[0] = foo bar` and `argv[1] = 40`.